# How can I declare local variable in Razor vb.net?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

it seems easy but I can't get it to work.
I am trying to declare a variable using vb.net in my layout.

I tried

```
@Dim lst As New List(Of String)
```

and also

```
@{Dim lst As New List(Of String)}
```

like I have seen in an other SO question but for C# and MVC3.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: For the first it's "expression expected" and for the second it's " '{' is not valid at the beginning of a code block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hear for VB you have to use `@Code...End Code` blocks, like so:

```
<!-- Declare variable  -->
@Code  Dim mood = "saucy"  End Code

<!-- Using the variable -->
<p>Today I am feeling: @mood</p>        

<!-- Multi-statement block -->    
@Code 
    Dim greeting = "Welcome to our site!"
    Dim weekDay = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek
    Dim greetingMessage = greeting & " Today is: " & weekDay.ToString()
End Code 
<p>The greeting is: @greetingMessage</p>
```

Example shamelessly ripped from: http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-vb